# How to print from Apps Script without using google CloudPrint?

Tags: google-apps-script, printing, google-cloud-print

I have a script from a Google spreadsheet, which generates several pdfs that correspond to different areas of the sheet, and then prints the pdfs files, using google cloud print, but now I have read that at the end of 2020 the Google Cloud Print disappears , how can I do it to print without Cloud Print?

Comment: Would `File > Download > PDF document (.pdf)` be a valid workaround for you?

Comment: No, I need print,  not generate a file PDF.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9633006?hl=en)?

Comment: Yes I checked, but I need an option to print from apps script. Thnak's.